# Why? Oauth: redirect_uri - must be the same as the provided in the first step

Tags: reactjs, github, oauth-2.0, vercel

I try to implement Stackoverflow Oauth 2.0 to my web app. But I do not get why second `redirect_uri` should be the same as the first?

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope

When I implemented Oauth 2.0 with Github I made this sequence. First call to Github is from frontend and the call expected back to frontend, second call is from backend and expected back to backend.

Of course redirect_uri is different. Why Stackoverflow works differently?

I implemented my solution with React app running on Vercel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is to protect someone from stealing the access token. If someone is able to get a hold of the request or the parameters needed for the request AND OAuth allowed the use a different redirect uri than where the original request came from, then that person could change the redirect uri to point to a url that that person controls and gain access.

Comment: Yes, theoretically yes. But in Gitlab and Facebook there is no such requirement. Anyway the down side of this requirement is, it is not possible make session based authentication.

Comment: You can have it redirect to your FE. If your BE really needs it, send the AT from FE to BE.

Comment: But if I send AT from FE to BE, than how BE validates AT that it was not tampered?

Comment: The AT should be signed. You can validate the signature to verify the contents. There are various libraries, or you could do it yourself (not recommended), or authorization servers sometimes have some kind of endpoint where you can send the AT and it'll validate the signature.